# Rails Devise after_sign_in_path_for(resource) method not functioning as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redirect, devise

I want to redirect an inactive user to the registration path to collect some information.  Here are two approaches I took but neither is working:

I overrode the devise after_sign_in_path method as follows (in **application_controller.rb**):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    debugger
    if(account_active)
        return root_path;
    else
        return edit_user_registration_path(resource)
    end
end
```

When I hooked the code upto debugger, I see that devise does call after_sign_in_path_for.  Also, the correct url is being generated by this call:

```
(rdb:2)  after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
"/users/edit.1"
```

However, when I look at the server logs, there is no attempt being made to redirect to     "/users/edit.1" under any circumstances.

I have tried moving the above method to **application_helper.rb,  session_controller.rb (by extending Devise::SessionController) and session_helper.rb**

The issue is that devise does call this method to retrieve the url but it never attempts the redirect.  I checked the web server logs, and devise directly goes to the user_root url.

Here is the relevant devise configuration from routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users do
    resource :registration,
    only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update],
    path: 'users',
    path_names: { new: 'sign_up' },
    controller: 'devise/registrations',
    as: :user_registration do
        get :cancel
    end


    root :to => "home#index"        
end

  match '/user' => "products#index", :as => 'user_root'
```

Any suggestions on what I should try?

Thanks,

Tabrez

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you want to redirect to `/users/edit.1`? Rails will pick that up as if you're trying to access the `1` mime-type instead of html.

The user registration path doesn't need an id, because it always belongs to the currently signed in user. This should be enough:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if account_active
    root_path
  else
    edit_user_registration_path
  end
end
```

Also, placing it in the `ApplicationController` is the right spot. If you have your own sessions controller, like `Users::SessionsController`, which inherits from `Devise::SessionsController`, than it can go in there too.

So either the `account_active` method doesn't do what you think it does, or you've screwed up the routes file. Try working with a more vanilla configuration in your routes to see if that is the case:

```
devise_for :users
```

PS. as a complete an utterly unrelated side note: please try to use Ruby coding conventions, like no semicolons when they're not needed, no parenthesis in `if` statements, 2-spaces indenting and no unneeded return statements.

Comment: Hi Iain - thanks for the reply.  Thanks for the tips. I just started on ruby, so there is lots of room for improvement on the coding style.  About the question, I looked at the code you are suggesting.  The only difference seems to be that you have edit_user_registration_path and I had changed my code to use edit_user_registration_path(resource).  Without the resource parameter, no route was generated by the method.  And, after putting that argument, rails is generating /users/edit.1 (I just copied it out of the debugger; I did not hardcode it).  I can try the simple route. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply to you, but in my recent use of devise + active_admin, I ran into the same problems you are describing.  I added the devise override while my development rails server was running, and assumed rails/devise would automatically pick up the method.  Apparently not since the problem was solved when I **restarted my server**.

It seems that devise is cherry picking these methods off `ApplicationController` when it initializes, though I havent looked at the source.